# Common Lisp: How to tell ASDF to act on a system which is already loaded

Tags: common-lisp, asdf

I know that I can say `(asdf:operate 'asdf:load-op <some-system>)` where `<some-system>` is a string which names a system, and there must be a file named `<some-system>.asd` in a directory known to ASDF, from which the system definition is loaded. So far, so good.

I am hoping to find a way to say something similar where `<some-system>` is an S-expression which is the system definition, i.e. it is `(defsystem "foo" ...)` which has been read in or constructed by some other means.

I guess it must be possible, since at some point ASDF must read the .asd file and then act on the resulting definition, but I haven't been able to puzzle it out. I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: why not evaluate the expression?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I was able to get it working, I'll post what I found as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, I was able to get it to work thanks to the hint from Rainer J.

`asdf:defsystem` is a macro which constructs a doodad of type ASDF/SYSTEM:SYSTEM. Then `asdf:operate` will take that as its argument instead of a string which names the system.

Here is a trivial example. I am working with SBCL 2.1.6 on an ancient Ubuntu system. The ASDF version is 3.3.something to judge by `*FEATURES*`.

In the current working directory, there is a file named `bar.lisp` which contains just

```
(defparameter baz 1234)
(format t "HELLO FROM BAR; BAZ = ~d~%" baz)
```

Now in the SBCL session I say:

```
* (require 'asdf)
NIL
* (asdf:defsystem "foo" :pathname #.*default-pathname-defaults* :components ((:file "bar")))
#<ASDF/SYSTEM:SYSTEM "foo">
```

to construct the system `foo`. To tell ASDF to look in the current working directory, the sharp-dot is necessary because otherwise `*DEFAULT-PATHNAME-DEFAULTS*` isn't evaluated (since ASDF:DEFSYSTEM is a macro). There are other ways to wedge the value in there (aside from just a string or pathname -- a pathname is maybe not supposed to work but I find it does), but anyway sharp-dot works.

With that system instance in hand, I can load it:

```
* (asdf:operate 'asdf:load-op *)
; compiling file "/home/robert/tmp/bar.lisp" (written 27 DEC 2022 10:10:04 AM):
; processing (DEFPARAMETER BAZ ...)
; processing (FORMAT T ...)

; wrote /home/robert/.cache/common-lisp/sbcl-2.1.6-linux-x86/home/robert/tmp/bar-tmp7LQ0A0VI.fasl
; compilation finished in 0:00:00.004
HELLO FROM BAR; BAZ = 1234
#<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP >
#<ASDF/PLAN:SEQUENTIAL-PLAN {9A633C49}>
```

and verify the variable BAZ is there:

```
* baz
1234
```

Ta-da!!